# I want to fix menu in the top With angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

My app use Angular,I want to fix menu on top When the position of the bar menu=0.

I have tried to use JavaScript, but I'am having a problem because the menu is an angular component.

NB: In the index component i call all components(menu, footer, head ...)

html:

```
<nav class="navbar" id="bar-menu">
  <ul>
   <li>Iteam 1</li>
   <li>Iteam 2</li>
   <li>Iteam 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
     myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
     var barmenu = document.getElementById("bar-menu");
     var barMenuTop = barmenu.offsetTop;
     if (document.body.scrollTop > barMenuTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > barMenuTop ) {
         document.getElementById("bar-menu").className="navbar affix";
     } else {
         document.getElementById("bar-menu").className="navbar";
    }
}
```

style css:

```
.affix{ position:fixed; top:0;}
```

the problem is the position of the bar menu is always having the value null barMenuTop=0.

Thanks advance.

Comment: That does not look as angular code at all

Comment: yes of course .

Comment: i want a solution to my problem please help me

Comment: Can you setup a plunkr or something? I'm with @Jota.Toledo, this looks like just plain javascript.